# Environment variable in zshrc file are not read by Skaffold for image tagging

Tags: docker, kubernetes, zshrc, skaffold

I'm just starting using Skaffold for Kubernetes development and I'm not able to tag the docker images created as I intended with environment variables as shown

```
tagPolicy:
    envTemplate:
      template: '{{.SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG}}'
    # dateTime:
    #   format: "2006-01-02_15-04-05.999_MST"
    #   timezone: "Local"
```

using dateTime works as expected but I'm not sure I'm setting correctly the environment variable I mean to use..

I added `export SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG=dev` to zshrc via `vim ~/.zshrc` but still but image has the `:latest` tag.
I tried `SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG="dev"` but didn't make a difference..

If I just set the variable in the VsCode terminal window with `export SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG=dev` it then works as expected tagging the image :dev
Why then the `zshrc` variable is not read?
Many thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need double-quotes around the template? Like

```
template: "{{.SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG}}"
```

I say this because single quotes `'` do not *expand* the variable defined in your environment and will translate to a literal `SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_NAME`. If put inside double quotes `"`, this will be exanded and interpreted as `$SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG`.

Otherwise, there is no reason for this to not work. As per the docs [here](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/taggers/#envtemplate-uses-values-of-environment-variables-as-tags).

Comment: I tried with double quotes as `template: "{{.SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG}}"` but had no luck, tried with  both `export SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG=dev` and `export SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG="dev"`.. the built image still gets tagged `:latest`.
Any other suggestion I could try?

Comment: where are you setting the variable?

Comment: in the zshell, I edit it with `vim ~/.zshrc`..Am I adding the environment variable in the wrong place?

Comment: as a test I also tried to set it in the Dockerfile and in the server deployment, not of the two gave results..

Comment: where is the correct place to put that env variable?